# appcenter error build for reactnative, looking for index.ios.js

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I have a react native project that I want to use appcenter with,

when building the project, I get the following error:

> ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
>   [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/_temp/4371836d-ad98-4059-84bc-f7bc51688d63.sh
>   Found index.ios.js for ReactNative index.
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>   error The resource `/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/index.ios.js` was not found.. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>    [error]Bash exited with code '1'.

But my react native project was created with expo, and in new schema after ejecting there is no index.ios.js or index.js

I also found this entry talking about it,
but dont understand yet how to add the index.js script
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/189

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and being track in GitHub. There is also a documented workaround on the GitHub Issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/189